# Wearing Tallit after the morning?

Tags: tefilla, tallit-gadol

If someone didn't wear a tallit during morning prayers, when they put it on in the afternoon let's say, do they make a bracha? Based on my searches online the info has been rather conflicting or just plain inexistent.

Answer (score 5):

One who puts on a *tallit* anytime during the day certainly fulfills a *mitzvah* and therefore makes the appropriate blessing. However, putting on a *tallit* at night may not fulfill a *mitzvah*, and therefore one does not bless. ([Rema to Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 18:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%97))

There is some controversy as to the definition of 'night' in this context: does it start at the beginning or the end of twilight? [Mishnah Berurah 18:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%97) rules that one may recite the blessing until he is certain that the twilight period has started.

If one has already prayed *arvit*, even if it is still daytime, one should not recite a blessing (Rema loc. cit.)